# Using global variables in middleman? i.e. Website title

Tags: javascript, ruby, static, yaml, middleman

I'm trying to find a way to use global variables within middleman, i.e. set website name and use it as a fallback if current page doesn't have a title or when passing app title parameter inside metas like `<meta name="application-name" content="Site name">` so I don't have to write this manually every time. Issue is that at present I am only able to get current page title like `<%= current_page.data.title || "Site Name" %>` where it is different for every layout, instead of `"Site Name"` I'd like to pass a global variable that is stored somewhere in one file and can be accessed by every page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [data files](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/data_files/). Simply create a file called *site.json* in the *data* folder at the root level of your project. You can then access it using the data path.

For example:

**data/site.json:**

```
{
  "title": "Foo Test"
}
```

**partials/head.html.erb** (or any other partial/layout/page)

```
<title><%= current_page.data.title || data.site.title %></title>
```

I just tested this out and it works for me using Middleman 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've used Middleman, but I think the way to do this is to use `set` in `config.rb`, e.g.:

```
set :site_title, "Site Name"
```

Then in your template you can access it with the `settings` object:

```
<%= current_page.data.title || config.site_title %>
```

Alternatively, you could create a helper method as described in [Custom Extensions](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/), e.g.:

```
class MyFeature < Middleman::Extension
  SITE_TITLE = "Site Name"

  helpers do
    def page_title
      current_page.data.title || SITE_TITLE
    end
  end
end
```

After activating the extension in `config.rb` you could then do this in your template:

```
<%= page_title %>
```

Then in your template you could just

Comment: almost right — you use the `config` object, not `settings`, like so: <%= config.site_title %>